# ASP.NET MVC - How to make it work with IIS6

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, deployment, iis-6, asp.net-4.0

I am having some issues with deploying my MVC 2 application on a IIS 6 server.

I have the following project structure:

```
/
   App/
      Controllers/
      Helpers/
      Infrastructure/
      Models/
      Views/
   Public/          # This folder contains CSS and JS files
   Global.asax
   Web.config
```

I have a custom `System.Web.Mvc.WebFormViewEngine` that tells my application to lookup the views in `/App/Views` instead of the default `/Views`.

It works fine on Cassini and IIS 7.5.

I need to deploy my application in a virtual directory on IIS 6 and I am getting 404 errors when trying to access any of my controllers.

I read that I needed to add a `Default.aspx` with the following code behind:

```
protected void Page_Load( object sender, EventArgs e ) {
    HttpContext.Current.RewritePath( Request.ApplicationPath, false );
    IHttpHandler httpHandler = new MvcHttpHandler();
    httpHandler.ProcessRequest( HttpContext.Current );
}
```

It actually called my default controller, and showed the corresponding view, but it's the only page I've been able to get so far.

I tried to enable the wildcard mapping, it didn't change anything. But I'm using ASP.NET 4.0, and [it enables routing of extension-less URLs](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tmarq/archive/2010/04/01/asp-net-4-0-enables-routing-of-extensionless-urls-without-impacting-static-requests.aspx).

I'm not really sure what to do now, I'm not finding any other helpful sources of information on the Internet.

How could I make it work?

Comment: Check out Phil Haack's Route Debugger: http://haacked.com/archive/2008/03/13/url-routing-debugger.aspx  And see what route it is looking for.

Comment: Oh that's really cool, I'm checking it out. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [this walkthrough](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/11/26/asp.net-mvc-on-iis-6-walkthrough.aspx) by Phil Haack.

Comment: I've read it a thousand times, and it's not helping me at all. I pretty much have the same configuration. Everything he says in that post is to enable wildcard mapping or use file extensions and change your routes.

Comment: It didn't really solve my problem, but I kind of solved it by adding a new application pool on IIS 6. I'm accepting this answer since that walk-through is a very good resource.

Answer (score 1):

Can't comment yet, but that walkthrough is it.
I did wildcard myself.

It was a while ago, so I don't remember the damn details of what I had to do to get it fixed now, but it took me a few hours.
I was missing some really small detail in his instructions, if I remember correctly.  What error/incorrect behavior are you getting?  You might trigger my memory.

Comment: I thought you didn't have to use wildcard mapping with ASP.NET 4.0 since it enables extension-less routing. I created a new application pool for my application instead of using the default one. I did everything again (including enabling wildcard mapping) and now it works.

Comment: I think IIS 6 is still a little bass ackwards.
Glad you got it working.